# Should I Develop For Symbian?

Tags: iphone, android, mobile, comparison, symbian

I looked it up on here, but I can't seem to find answers to the questions I'm looking for. I currently make HTML5 apps for iPhones, and was going to get more into the native side, but I've read Symbian actually has the most share (near 50%). My questions are:

1. Is it profitable to develop for Symbian? E.g. if i made the same app for iPhone, Android or Symbian, which would bring in the most money based on statistics (and do you have a source?)
2. Is it easy? I read you can write apps for it in HTML5 and JS, but is that easy and does it let you use the entire phones API?

Thoughts?

Comment: Whats your target?  You know symbian is big but not in the US.  So if you don't plan on localizing for Asia how much sense does it make to develop for symbian.

Comment: I've heard it's large in the EU also, is it not? I'm just curious I don't know.

Comment: Hi sure - in EU it is number one OS: http://www.allaboutsymbian.com/news/item/11342_comScore_data_shows_smartphone.php

Answer (score 0):

Our company move from symbian to android and window 7, becouse android is more open and progresive and there are many peoples who think that symbian is "dead".. sorry) but its only in my company

Comment: Yeah, interesting, thanks. But thats why I was asking since Symbian share has actually been increasing, even this year. I think it's odd esp since i never heard of it (since they don't really sell Symbian here in the U.S.)

Comment: I think android is a future more and more new devices working on it and some one say that nokia wana move from symbian to MeeGo OS. Think you must analyse your opportunities and market situation. I wish you a good start in android development